# Codeigniter can't update the form when click submit

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, codeigniter

I'm having trouble with codeigniter, when I click on submit it won't update the data.

I'm creating the super admin so it can delete or update the normal admin data.

Here's my code:

**controller**

```
<?php

class Superadmin extends MY_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //$this->session->userdata('is_login') == FALSE || redirect('admin/Login_admin');
        if($this->session->userdata('token'))
        $this->session->unset_userdata('token');
        $this->load->model('admin/Admin_m');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        if(isset($this->session->id)=='') 
        {
            redirect('admin/Login');
        }

        $data['content'] = 'page/admin/superadmin';
        $data['admin'] = $this->Admin_m->get_all();
        $this->load->view('layout_admin', $data);
    }

    public function editadmin($admin_id)
    {
        if(isset($this->session->id)=='') 
        {
            redirect('admin/Login');
        }

        $data['content'] = 'page/admin/superadminedit';
        $data['admin']   = $this->Admin_m->get_admin_by_id($admin_id);

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('page/admin/superadminedit', $data);
        }
        else
        {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('full_name', ' Full name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('user', 'Username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[5]');
            // kondisi untuk input data jika password kosong
            if($this->input->post('password') == ''){
                $data = 
                array(
                'full_name' => $this->input->post('full_name'),
                'user'      => $this->input->post('user'),
                'level'     => $this->input->post('level'),
                );
            }
            else
            {
            $data = 
                array(
                'full_name' => $this->input->post('full_name'),
                'user'      => $this->input->post('user'),
                'password'  => hashpassword($this->input->post('password')),
                'level'     => $this->input->post('level'),
                );
            }
                $this->Admin_m->edit_admin($admin_id,$data);
                redirect('admin/superadmin/editadmin');
        } 
    }


    public function deleteadmin($id)
    {
        if(isset($this->session->id)=='') 
        {
            redirect('admin/Login');
        }

        $this->load->model('Admin_m');

        $this->Admin_m->delete($id);

        //$this->session->set_flashdata('remove_success', 'Admin berhasil dihapus dari List');

        redirect('admin/Superadmin');
    }

}

?>
```

**model**

```
<?php

class Admin_m extends CI_Model
{
    public function check_akunadmin($user= '' , $password = '')
    {
        return $this->db->get_where('admin_user', 
            array('user' =>$user, 
                  'password' => hashpassword($password)
                  )
                    )->row();

    }

    public function insert($data = array())
    {
        $this->db->insert('admin_user',$data);
    }

    public function edit_admin($id, $data = array())
    {
         $this->db->where('id', $id);
         $this->db->set($data);
         $this->db->update('admin_user');
    }

    public function get_admin_by_id($admin_id)
    {
        return $this->db->get_where('admin_user', array('id' => $admin_id))->row();
    }

    public function get_all($per_page = 0, $offset = 0)
    {
        $this->db->order_by('id', 'desc');
        return $this->db->limit($per_page, $offset)->get('admin_user')->result();
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->delete('admin_user'); 
    }

}

?>
```

**view**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>AdminLTE 2 | General Form Elements</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>backendtampilan/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>backendtampilan/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
  <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
       folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>backendtampilan/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
<div class="wrapper">

  <header class="main-header">
    <!-- Logo -->
    <a class="logo">
      <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
      <span class="logo-mini"><b>A</b>LT</span>
      <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
      <span class="logo-lg"><b>Admin</b>LTE</span>
    </a>
    <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
  </header>
  <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->

  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <h1>
        Edit Admin
      </h1>
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <!-- left column -->
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <!-- general form elements -->
          <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h3 class="box-title">Super Admin edit Page</h3> <br>
              <a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/superadmin')?>"><button class="btn btn-primary">Back to Super Admin</button></a>
               <?php if(validation_errors()): ?>
                <ul class="alert alert-danger"><?php echo validation_errors('<li>','</li>')?></ul>
             <?php endif;?>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <!-- form start -->
                <form action="<?php echo base_url(). 'admin/superadmin/editadmin/'. $admin->id; ?>" method="post" enctype ="multipart/form-data">
              <div class="box-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>ID</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ID" value="<?php echo $admin->id ?>" disabled>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label >Full Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="full_name"  placeholder="Enter Name" value="<?php echo $admin->full_name ?>">
                </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                  <label>User</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" value="<?php echo $admin->user ?>">
                </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                  <label>New Password</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password" >
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Level</label><br>
                <select name="level">
                  <option value="0">Super Admin</option>
                  <option value="1">Normal Admin</option>
                </select>
              </div>

              </div>
              <!-- /.box-body -->

              <div class="box-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box -->
        <!--/.col (right) -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
  <footer class="main-footer">
    <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
    </div>
     All rights reserved.
  </footer>


<!-- ./wrapper -->

<!-- jQuery 2.2.3 -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>backendtampilan/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>backendtampilan/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>backendtampilan/plugins/fastclick/fastclick.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>backendtampilan/dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>backendtampilan/dist/js/demo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

after i click submit on the view page it just wont updating in the database...

what went wrong? i hope someone understand and explain it to me...

thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: Looks like `<form action="<?php echo base_url(). 'admin/superadmin/editadmin/'. $admin->id; ?>"` maybe should be `<form action="<?php echo base_url(). 'superadmin/editadmin/'. $admin->id; ?>"` (no leading "admin"). But without your routes its also hard to know. In the future, try submit a minimal example of the problem to reduce the amount of code someone has to look through. One form, one endpoint, and the routes might be sufficient.

Comment: i add folder admin to my controller so i know the controller is for admin so the result is like admin/superadmin/editadmin/ and if i dont use admin for example the result is account/update_account.. sorry if it look confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
public function edit_admin($id, $data = array())
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('admin_user', $data);
}
```

Also, do a print_r($data);exit; right before the where to check if the model is receiving the data properly.

OFF: Let me give you a hand here... There's no need to repeat the entire array.

```
if($this->input->post('password') == ''){
    $data = 
    array(
        'full_name' => $this->input->post('full_name'),
        'user'      => $this->input->post('user'),
        'level'     => $this->input->post('level'),
    );
}
else
{
    $data = 
    array(
        'full_name' => $this->input->post('full_name'),
        'user'      => $this->input->post('user'),
        'password'  => hashpassword($this->input->post('password')),
        'level'     => $this->input->post('level'),
    );
}
```

Should be:

```
$data = 
array(
    'full_name' => $this->input->post('full_name'),
    'user'      => $this->input->post('user'),
    'level'     => $this->input->post('level'),
);

if(!empty($this->input->post('password'))){
    $data['password'] = hashpassword($this->input->post('password'));
}
```

Comment: after i change to your code i get Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `id` = '7'' at line 2

UPDATE `admin_user` SET `content` = 'page/admin/superadminedit', `admin` = WHERE `id` = '7'                                                                                         
                                                                                                                  
 what went wrong?

Comment: also if i do print_r($data) the result is this:  Array ( [content] => page/admin/superadminedit [admin] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 7 [full_name] => budisa [user] => admin6 [password] => ca1b76fb3daf260d8c077b8929e173193470523b38a4b1f00e604183c9a694f1c9c12b54dced4a0965e1f34ed3cc3ffcdb84209214b342d98e0ea31b6fdc9580 [level] => 0 ) )

Comment: Yeap, I didn't notice this...
You are using $data['content'] and $data['admin'] to send it to your view. But you're also using $data to send it to your model. You should order it properly to differentiate the VIEW part (when you show the form), to the POST part (when you receive the data). You can change the $data behind the form_validation to $data_post (or something like this) for now. Remember that the model is expecting to receive an ARRAY of data and you are sending an array who includes content, admin and another array of the post. (You turn it multidimensional by accident). Good luck!

Comment: Good catch. Indeed you are sending your view data array to your edit function which is causing your problems. It's generally a good idea to use different variable names to avoid confusion and these issues. Also, it might just be me, but if someone takes the time to go through that much code and even if it doesn't answer your question but provides a solid helping hand - give that man a cookie. Or in this case... An up vote :)